# How to match a regex in python, either completely or partially

Tags: python, regex

This is a basic question but I've searched a bit and am still having doubts.

Let's take the following regex as an example:

```
regex_example = re.compile('\d{10}\s\d-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
```

Now let's imagine there is a string which may contain substrings matching the full length of that regex, such as '1234567890 1-123-456-7890' or it may just contain substrings that match the first part of the regex, say for example '1234567890 1-123'.

I would like to modify the regex (or use another solution) allowing me to match any substring that has 14 or more char and matches the regex either partially or entirely. So my code would find:

'1234567890 1-1' (has 14 characters and matches the start of the regex)
or
'1234567890 1-13'
or
'1234567890 1-134'

And so forth, up to the full length of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make part after first 14 characters optional:

```
regex_example = re.compile(
   '(\d{10}\s\d-\d(?:\d{0,2}(?:(?:-\d{0,3})?(?:-\d{0,4})?)?)?)')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM1nJ4/3)

Comment: Apologies, I don't follow. Your link shows that there is only one match when I look at the Match window on the right hand side ('23-456-7890'). That's what I got with my test too.

Comment: The thing is given the test string 'bla 1234567890 1-123-456-7890 bla', when I run 'regex_example.findall(test_str)' the output is ['23-456-7890']. I would be expecting ['1234567890 1-123-456-7890'] (a full match) in that case.

Comment: It is indeed, but it's still not what I need. Making this an optional group is making the match be either a full match or a match without the optional group at all. Read the last bit of my original question. But thanks anyway...

Comment: Exactly. Catching 14 char is partial, catching 15 char is partial, and so forth, until we get the full match. I provided examples so make it clearer but if you want to suggest how I can improve the initial question I'm open to that. Tx.

Comment: Yes, it works. And like I've said, I'm happy to rephrase my question if you want to be specific on how it can be improved.